# apt - How disable the fetching of the Contents files?

Tags: linux, debian, shell, ubuntu, apt

When `apt update` I want to avoid download all tthe contents.gz files to spare time and network resources. How could this be done with command line options nor configuration files?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`apt` doesn’t download `Contents` files by default; if it’s doing so on your system, it’s probably because you have `apt-file` installed too. In that case, to disable `Contents` downloads, disable the corresponding configuration file:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50apt-file.conf{,.disabled}
```

This will cause `apt update` to skip `Contents` files. As a result, `apt-file` will fail to work, or at best, operate on obsolete information; to be able to use it and to update its indexes, re-enable the configuration file:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50apt-file.conf{.disabled,}
```

and run `apt update` again.

Comment: not working on Debian unstable now. Current Debian version is 11. disabling the config prevents apt-file from running any command.

Comment: @FaridCheraghi indeed, thanks; I’ve updated the answer to indicate that `apt-file` may stop working entirely.