# 'sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y' on Kali Linux failed

Tags: kali-linux, upgrade

I am trying to update and upgrade **Kali Linux** with `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y` but I receive the following issue. How can I solve this problem? Anyone can help me, please.

```
┌──(kali㉿`enter code here`)-[~]
└─$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -y
Get:1 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease [30.6 kB]
Get:2 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free Sources [123 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib Sources [66.3 kB]
Get:4 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main Sources [14.4 MB]
Get:5 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Packages [18.0 MB]
Get:6 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb) [40.9 MB]
Get:6 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb) [40.9 MB]
Get:6 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb) [40.9 MB]
Ign:6 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb)
Err:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb)      
  File has unexpected size (40914837 != 40904768). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 118.38.178.199 80]
Get:9 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Contents (deb) [129 kB]
Ign:9 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Contents (deb)   
Err:6 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/main amd64 Contents (deb)                                 
  File has unexpected size (40914837 != 40904768). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 118.38.178.199 80]
Get:10 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Contents (deb) [949 kB]               
Ign:10 http://ftp.harukasan.org/kali kali-rolling/non-free amd64 Contents (deb)
Ign:9 http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling/contrib amd64 Contents (deb)
Reading package lists... Done                       
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/main/Contents-amd64  File has unexpected size (40914837 != 40904768). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 118.38.178.199 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/kali-rolling/contrib/Contents-amd64  File has unexpected size (154305 != 128561). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 118.38.178.199 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**Version of Kali:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2022.1
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

**What I've tried so far:**

- The following commands from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329450/e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used):

  ```
   sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list ~/ 
   sudo wget "http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=uzhrtg5M" -O /etc/apt/sources.list 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-extras.list
   sudo apt-get update
  ```
- `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get upgrade -f` from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89729/a-problem-occurred-when-checking-for-updates-error)

  ```
   apt-get clean
  ```

I have read lots of articles but none of the mentioned solutions worked for me. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [apt - How disable the fetching of the Contents files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494201/apt-how-disable-the-fetching-of-the-contents-files)

Comment: Why would you replace your Kali repositories with Ubuntu's? Please don't run random commands you don't understand. You need to put your original `/etc/apt/sources.list` back. You can't just install things from Ubuntu's repos! Kali is a tool for professionals, it should not be used unless you are a security professional. Please, please read https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/ and install a normal Linux distribution to learn on before you try using Kali.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message seems pretty clear:

```
File has unexpected size (40914837 != 40904768). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 118.38.178.199 80]
```

The mirror from which you're using to download updates is being synchronised from its upstream source. Try again later or temporarily use a different mirror

Answer (score 4):

Whatever the exact problem with the failing files, those `Contents` files are not needed to handle packages or package upgrades. They are downloaded in addition to the needed files for the benefit of the package [`apt-file`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/apt-file) (Debian: [`apt-file`](https://packages.debian.org/stable/apt-file))  to make easy a search of arbitrary package contents even if the package is not installed and they are usually big.

So to work around this until the dist upgrade is done, simply remove `apt-file`:

```
apt-get purge apt-file
```

You can still reinstall it later and see if it works correctly then.

Or instead of removing the package, it can be temporarily disabled as described there: [apt - How disable the fetching of the Contents files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494201/apt-how-disable-the-fetching-of-the-contents-files/495022#495022)

Comment: It doesn’t even need to be uninstalled, it [can be disabled](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495022/86440) temporarily.

Comment: @StephenKitt Indeed your answer works as-is to this question